# Why if unity is not an eigeinvalue of A then (I - A) is nonsingular?

Tags: matrices

Seems so obvious but I can't get it:

> If unity is **not** an eigenvalue of $A$, then $(I - A)$ is nonsingular.

How can I prove this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the definition, when $(I-A)$ is singular it means $(1 \cdot I -A)$ has a non trivial kernel, which means there is a $v\neq 0 $ such that 
$$(I-A)v=0$$ 
which would mean, that $A$ has the eigenvalue 1.

Answer (score 2):

Let $1$ not be an eigenvalue of $A$ but $I-A$ is singular.

Thus,
Using the [Characteristic Polynomial Approach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial#Characteristic_equation)

\begin{align}
\det(A-\lambda I)&=0\\
\text{We Know,}\\
\det(A-I)&=0\\
\end{align}
Thus, $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

Contradiction!